# How to exit app using ionic 4 on app load when it doesnt find internet?

Tags: ionic-framework, networking, ionic4

how can i exit my app when it doesnt find internet?
I want it to show the user a dialog box "No internet conncetion", and a ok button when pressed, it closes the app.
Thanks

Answer (score 12):

`this.platform.exitApp()` seems to be removed from ionic version 4.
Try:

```
navigator['app'].exitApp();
```

p.

Answer (score -1):

try below code **this.platform.exitApp();**

```
constructor(public platform : Platform){
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
                    if (this.alertShown == false) {
                        this.presentConfirm();
                        this.alertShown = true
                    }
                }, 0);


}
        presentConfirm() {
                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: 'Confirm',
                    message: 'Do you want to exit?',
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: 'Cancel',
                            role: 'cancel',
                            handler: () => {
                                console.log('Cancel clicked');
                                this.alertShown = false;
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Yes',
                            handler: () => {
                                console.log('Yes clicked');
                                this.platform.exitApp();
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
                alert.present().then(() => {
                    //this.alertShown=true;
                });
            }
```